# Displaying progress on imagebutton

Tags: android

I have  a imagebutton, clicking on it triggeres a async task. Therefore, until the task completes I want to set a loading gif as the image source to the image button. Can I do this? Are there any elegant ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not move away from using an ImageButton and instead use a RelativeLayout that you can format to look like a button, but can contain Android ProgressBar? You can set it to indeterminate (if you just want a spinning loading animation) and customize the look of it as you wish.

Comment: I have the button inside a linear layout, which again is in another linear layout and the whole layout is in a frame layout. Will it not complicate to use another layout for the image?  how does the performance differ between using the these two?

Comment: Can you add a code sample? Should I create a anim.xml for my loader?

Comment: It shouldn't complicate/impact performance much (if at all), replace your button with a relativeLayout, and place whatever elements you need inside of it. You don't need an anim.xml.. just use the built in [ProgressBar widget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html).